# Google Shopping API using OAuth 2 method for authentication

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am trying to create a console app that will be executed by a scheduled task to create products for sale on Google Shopping.  From what I have read OAuth 2 is the method of Authentication I should be using.

In the Google Developer Console I have created a Project and got back a Project Id.  I have enabled the Content API for Shopping, Created a Client Id for native application which gives me the Client Id, Client Secret and Redirect URIS. (not sure what the Redirect URIS are all about?)

In my C# code I have:

```
    string clientId = "27127807975-j71ghj7<=== MY CLIENT ID from console ===>apps.googleusercontent.com";  // Provided in the APIs Console
    string clientSecret = "WFM<== My Secret from console ==>osVg";  // Provided in the APIs Console
    string scope = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
    string redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

    OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters()
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        ClientSecret = clientSecret,
        RedirectUri = redirectUri,
        Scope = scope
    };

    string authorizeUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
```

However the URL returned from this call gives this error when loaded in browser, (I read I need to load this url in a browser to get an Access Code returned):

```
 Error: invalid_client
 no application name
```

Would really like to know what I am doing wrong here or maybe a link to some example code that posts a product to Google Shopping if anyone knows of any.

Comment: you might want to consider using googles client libs http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Content.v2/